# How to use the branch and trunk in SVN with the dev server?

Tags: php, svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn

I develop in PHP with NetBeans. The modifications are uploaded to a virtualized LAMP dev server on my machine directly by NetBeans.

I would like to branch some developments.

The problem is that only the trunk is sent to the server.

I use a classic structure:

```
{svnroot}/trunk 
{svnroot}/branches 
{svnroot}/tags
```

How can I test the branches without doing a crazy branch/trunk swap (with all the possible conflicts)?

- Is there a solution with an htaccess configuration?
- Should I use SVN differently?
- Should I use NetBeans differently?

Answer (score 0):

Most SVN setups have a few top-level directories

```
{svnroot}/trunk
{svnroot}/branches
{svnroot}/tags
```

If you lack the "branches" top-level directory, add it.  Then use `svn copy` to copy in all the contents from "trunk".

If your web server pulls the code in such a manner that your "branches" directory gets pulled into the web server, that's a deployment issue concerning your web server, and whoever set that up needs to fix it.

Sometimes a person side-steps having a release plan by doing a `svn checkout` of the code directly into the web server.  While that works for a very limited number of cases, it reduces your ability to handle future events without migrating to a more sophisticated release plan.  If your environment tends to do something like this, you might be able to continue to follow your plan by selectively checking out only the sub-contents of "trunk", or you could migrate to a proper "build" of your release, which then goes through a "deployment plan".

If you lack the "trunk" directory, before attempting anything, you might have to create the "trunk" directory and move all of the current contents into it.  This means that all development would need to checkout from the "trunk" subdirectory instead of the {svnroot} directory.  This is done by extending your URL (adding "/trunk" to the end).

I hope this gets you thinking along the right paths.

Comment: I have this classic setup (trunk+branches+tags). The problem is that only the trunk is sent to the website root. So how can I test the branch I am working on on the dev web server? Should I send the whole svnroot and have an apache config to handle which version of the site to test like: http://branch11.myproject.dev, http://branch12.myproject.dev, etc.?

Comment: You need to set up your own web server, and then checkout the branch to that web server.

Comment: So all the branches, tags and the trunk should be pushed to the web server? And we have to handle all the subdomains through url rewrite. Sounds strange... A simpler solution must exist...

Comment: @Toto, No, all the branches tags and such _should not_ be pushed to the web server.  You should checkout _your specific branch_ and deploy _that specific branch_ to your _testing web server_ which you will use to verify the development done in _your specific branch_

Comment: So I would have to change the project properties (Project Properties > Sources > Web Root) in Netbeans each time I work on a different branch and would have to upload the whole branch for synchronisation... if I get it correctly...

Comment: Yes, but your netbeans config files should be saved in each branch, so you don't need to change on a per-branch basis, you just need to "switch" branches and possibly restart netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout everything onto the web server, and use symbolic links (or junction points with Windows servers - see [Junction.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) from www.sysinernals.com ) to switch between test/production environments.  Or yes, you could use .htaccess to change where your web root points to.  As others have said, it's usually a good idea to have separate test/production servers.

Comment: I cannot check out the whole SVN database to the webserver. Too much data and too complicated to handle the subdomains, url rewrite conflicts with such a configuration. :(